# Как корректно импортировать время в формате UTC из CSV в MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, csv, импорт

Экспортировала из Mongo в формат CSV, далее мне нужно импортировать в Mysql.
Даты в файле имеют формат `2012-12-01T00:00:00.000Z` , есть пустые ячейки дат (мешают ли пустые ячейки при импорте,можно ли их заменить на поля null?)

Пробовала все типы дат (`DATETIME` итд) для выгрузки использую `Table Data Import Wizatd`, **выдает ошибку** **1292**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

единственно `YEAR` - выдает , что неполная форма даты.

Файл выглядит примерно так

```
14669,500 / 595 / 695 (312_),2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,,3854
14671,GRANDE PUNTO (199_),2007-12-01T00:00:00.000Z,2012-12-01T00:00:00.000Z,3854
38287,PUNTO EVO (199_),2008-07-01T00:00:00.000Z,2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z,3854
```

Comment: *Файл выглядит примерно так* Примерный ответ подойдёт? нет? тогда скопируйте несколько (3-4) строк из своего CSV и вставьте в текст вопроса (форматировать как код). Если в нём есть служебные символы, замените на соответствующие MySQL-литералы (например, знак табуляции на `\t`).

Comment: PS. Формат `2012-12-01T00:00:00.000Z` невалиден для MySQL как формат литерала даты. Конвертируйте в `2012-12-01 00:00:00.000` либо используйте STR_TO_DATE().